# How to make use of Internal Oscillator in PIC16F676?

Tags: pic, embedded, pickit

Im a beginner in PIC and using PIC16F676 for making an LED blinking program. But every tutorial uses an external oscillator. I want to make use of the internal oscillator to do this, so can anyone guide?

Comment: Have you read section 9.2 of the datasheet?

Comment: Okay, Thank You @HandyHowie, Saw  INTOSC Internal Oscillator (2 modes)

Comment: The PIC16F676 is a bad device to start with when trying to understand how to use Microchip controllers. Please for your own sake try to get something more current.

Comment: Okay @Dan1138 , could you suggest a beginners PIC? I'll start with that.

Comment: @reejesh-pk, It is almost impossible to chose a worse PIC to start with. It would help if you could list some of the PIC part numbers that you can actually get for prices you can afford from sources local to you. Any of the PIC18F parts could be a good choice. Also the type of device programming tools you have can can help you focus on what to start with.

Comment: Okay @Dan1138,Thank you